# Interrupt system calls on multiple threads

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

I have a bunch of pthreads, each blocking on a system call such as `recv()` and `wait()`.

I want to interrupt them (and make them return with errno = `EINTR`) when a signal arrives, so I use `sigaction()` without `SA_RESTART` to set an interrupt handler. The end goal is to gracefully exit the whole program.

However, it seems that only the thread that handles the signal got interrupted, while the other threads keep blocking on their system calls.

How do I interrupt all of them?

Comment: How about [`pthread_kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) in a loop to send a signal to all your threads?

Answer (score 3):

[signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)-s are not friendly with [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) (which on Linux are implemented with [clone(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html))

Consider (like [Qt](https://qt.io/) does) having some event loop in every thread, and use [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). It is compatible with [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) so with [socket(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html).

Alternatively, set some *global* `volatile sigatomic_t flag;` in your signal handler, and test that flag in every thread. See also [`<stdatomic.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)

Be aware of the [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) paradigm.

Comment: This answer is completely contrary to OP's needs, which are specifically interrupting and very intentionally integrated with multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

In order to interrupt all of them, you need to use `pthread_kill` to signal them each individually, rather than signaling the process, which means you need to keep a list of the threads you may want to signal. Note that since it's always possible for the signal to arrive after the last check before the blocking syscall, but before the syscall is actually made, it's always necessary to repeat the signaling (with appropriate backoff) until the signaled thread responds in some way to indicate that it has accepted the interruption request. This is a race condition *inherent* in the original concept of interruption-by-signal, even without threads.

If it's your intent that the threads terminate shortly after interrupting the syscalls they're blocking in, you could use *Thread Cancellation* instead of signals. This does not require dealing with the problems of `EINTR` (the aforementioned race condition, among other things) but does require structuring your code around the possibility of cancellation. That means enabling/disabling cancellation according to whether the code executing is prepared to handle it, and setting up cancellation handlers to back out any inconsistent state, free resources, release locks, etc. as appropriate.

If you do use signals, `volatile sigatomic_t` objects should not play any role in the solution. The signal handler can and should be a completely empty function; its only purpose is to cause `EINTR`. The signaling thread and signaled thread should communicate via standard pthread synchronization primitives (mutexes, possibly condition variables, and/or semaphores) to indicate the request to abort the operation and to acknowledge action on the request.

Comment: *you could use Thread Cancellation instead of signals*  I would personally not do that.  I'd probably use a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag to indicate state, and then handle `EINTR` based on the value of that state.  Writing correct multithreaded code that allows for clean thread cancellation is ***hard*** - at any cancellation point the thread could simply disappear.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's why you need cancellation handlers and enabling/disabling of cancellation at appropriate points. `volatile sigatomic_t` is not an ingredient in any solution to this though. The only point of the signal handler is to cause `EINTR`; the function body should be empty. You read the event via shared state controlled by a mutex and stored by the signaling thread, not state written by the signal handler.

Comment: *You read the event via shared state controlled by a mutex and stored by the signaling thread, not state written by the signal handler.*  That works, but a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag set by the signal handler could do that without the mutex.  And cancellation handlers add a whole lot of complexity. Multithreaded code is hard enough to get right in the first place.  I personally prefer a simpler solution, especially given I aim for being able to recover from `SIGKILL` at any time on the entire process.  You have to do that for true robustness anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It's true that you could use a `_Thread_local volatile sigatomic_t` set by the signal handler (assuming you interpret the standard as allowing access to a `_Thread_local` one) to see the *request* for interruption without synchronization, but that doesn't buy you anything since you need synchronization to send the acknowledgement back (for reasons described in my answer). The empty handler function approach is at least as simple. All it involves is `if (ret<0 && errno==EINTR) { lock(); if (intr_flag) { mark_ack(); need_intr=true; } unlock(): } ... if (need_intr) ...`